# alignment of divs inside one another

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

```
<div style="height:25px; margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; position: relative;">
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~deliveryvan.jpg" Height="75px" Width="100px" /><br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" NavigateUrl="~/List.aspx" runat="server" Text="Deliveries"></asp:HyperLink>
    <% if (NumerofDeliveries > 0) %>
     <% { %>
       <div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; border:1px solid;  border-color:#EBEBFF; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;"><%:NumerofDeliveries%></div> 
      <% } %>
        </div>
```

I would like to place the div containing the numbers in the top right of the box.
I can do this by removing margin-top:12px; from the original div. however I need to keep margin-top:12px;  as I want the images to have padding.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use - margin value for the numbers.

```
margin-top:-12px;
```